# Read Coordinates from file in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, file, coordinates

I have file in javascript i am opening using

```
fs.readFileSync(fileName)
```

after I return it to the client it is stored like so:

```
[G]Hey, where did [C]we go, da[G]ys when the ra[D]ins came
[G]Down in the holl[C]ow, [G]playin' a ne[D]w game
```

However, I need the x and y coordinates so that I can update my canvas.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: X y coordinates of what?

Comment: Of the words within the file

Comment: Files don’t have xy coordinates.

Comment: Would it be possible to add x and y coordinates as I am reading the file?

Comment: Provide a sample input, and a sample expected output. See creating a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If we assume the first character has the position `{x: 0, y: 0}` and that the next line increments the y position by one, then we can use something like this to calculate the positions of the characters:

```js
/**
 * Find the XY positions of this string
 *
 * @type {string}
 */
const given = `[G]Hey, where did [C]we go, da[G]ys when the ra[D]ins came
[G]Down in the holl[C]ow, [G]playing a ne[D]w game`;

/**
 * Return the coordinates of the characters in a string
 *
 * @param {string} string
 * @returns {Array}
 */
const calculateXY = (string) => {
    const positions = [];
    let yIndex = 0;
    let xIndex = 0;

    string.split('').forEach(character => {
        if(/\n/g.test(character)) {
            yIndex++;
            xIndex = 0;
        } else {
            positions.push({ [character]: { x: xIndex, y: yIndex}});
        }

        xIndex++;
    });

    return positions;
};

const result = calculateXY(given);
console.log(result);
```

You can modify the above block an pass a multiplier so that x and y are incremented by the distance in pixels to the next character.